# Having a value one or more times in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a very simple table in SQL Server:

```
dbo.plate
   plate_id
   plate
   datetime
   inserted_at
```

I want to do a query with the result e.g.:

80% of the plates are there only once.
20% of the plates are more then one time in the table.

How can this be done?

Started with something like:

```
SELECT count(plate)
FROM pos.dbo.plate
GROUP BY plate
HAVING count(plate) > 1
```

Comment: Please use DISTINCT.

Comment: In this case we must be extremely carefully.

Comment: If NULLs are allowed

Comment: RewriteWHERE clause such: WHERE derived.plate = pp.plate or derived.plate IS NULL and pp.plate IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for? Use a CTE/Sub-query to give each plate a value then sum and divide.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Plate(plate varchar(32));

INSERT INTO dbo.Plate(plate)
VALUES ('1'),('1'),('2');

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT plate, COUNT(plate) plateCount
    FROM dbo.plate
    GROUP BY plate
)
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(9,2),100*SUM(CASE WHEN plateCount > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(plateCount*1.0)) PercentageMoreThanOnePlate
FROM cte;
```

Returns:

| PercentageMoreThanOnePlate |
| --- |
| 33.33 |

Note: Providing the DDL+DML as shown here makes it much easier to answer.

Answer (score -1):

My proposition of result

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(plate) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over_1
    , SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(plate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) equal_1
    , SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(plate) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / SUM(1) More_than_1_percent
    , SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(plate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / SUM(1) Equal_than_1_percent
FROM
    dbo.plate
GROUP BY
    plate;
```

Comment: Gives the error `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.` - please ensure your solution works before posting.

Comment: Sorry @DaleK but in Oracle it works fine so I'm very surprised this simple query does not in SSQL

Comment: Every RDBMS has a different SQL dialect, even things that you would consider simple will differ between products. You need to be aware of what product a question is concerning and make sure your answer is suitable.

Answer (score -1):

I just did this:

```
WITH CTE as (
    SELECT count(plate) as counting
    FROM POS.dbo.plate
    GROUP BY plate
)
SELECT 
    count(Case WHEN counting > 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'returning customers'
    ,count(case WHEN counting = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'New customers'
FROM CTE
```

it gives me:

**Returning Customer: 122**
**New Customer: 3.525**

Not in percent, but close ;-)

Answer (score -1):

And at the end I come up with:

```
WITH CTE as (
    SELECT count(plate) as counting
    FROM POS.dbo.plate
    GROUP BY plate
)
SELECT 
    Convert(decimal(9,2),100*cast(sum(Case WHEN counting > 1 then counting ELSE NULL END) as real)/cast(sum(counting) as real)) as 'Returning customers'
    ,Convert(decimal(9,2),100*cast(sum(case WHEN counting = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as real)/cast(sum(counting) as real)) as 'New customers'
FROM CTE;
```

Is there a more elegant way to work with the number formats?

The Result now gives me 6,84% and 93,16% for the both values.

Comment: Looks pretty much like you've borrowed from my answer... so you should at a minimum credit it and maybe consider awarding me the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by a more elegant way?

Comment: I mean a not so nested way of doing it with the Convert and Cast thing. I put the cast in the CTE *cast(count(plate) as real) that makes things a little shorter.

Comment: You certainly don't want to be casting to `real` - thats for scientific numbers only and doesn't necessarily display an accurate result when working in decimals.